# Lower Bound of $x(P)$ in terms of coefficient $a, b$ of an Elliptic Curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties

According to Hall–Lang conjecture there are absolute constants $C$ and $κ$ such that for every elliptic curve $E/Q$ given by a Weierstrass equation $E:=y^2=x^3+ax^2+b$ with $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$
and for every integral point $P ∈ E(Q)$, i.e., satisfying $x(P) ∈ \mathbb{Z}$, we have-

$$x(P)\leq  C \times \text{max}\{|a|, |b|\}^κ$$

Here, $x(P)$ is the coordinate on $x$ axis of the point $P$ on the ellptic curve $E$. The above conjecture gives an upper bound of $x(P)$.  Is there anything known  regarding the lower bound of $x(P)$ in terms of $a, b$ ?

Comment: If you are asking how "negative" an *x*-coordinate can be,  doesn't the same conjecture address the lower bound issue by replacing *x,b* with *-x,-b*?

Comment: @hardmath no that is not what I mean, also, $x(P)$ is not given as absolute value.

Comment: If you consider the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+n^2-1$, then the point $(1,n)$ is on the curve, so $x(P)=1$ while $b=n^2-1$ can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: Note that if $(x_0,y_0)$ is a point on (the curve with affine equation) $y^2=x^3+ax+b$, then $x_0^3+ax_0+b\ge 0$. So $x_0$ is bigger than the smallest real root of the cubic $x\to x^3+ax+b$. Is this the point asked for?!